# check if value is above 0 not working

Tags: php, html

```
$number1 = $_POST['zombie'];
if ($number1 > 0){
echo "greater than 0";
}
```

Now my script just says when the $_POST is -1 that it still is greater than 0.
Is there some code that checks for values under 0?

Try #2:

```
$number1 = $_POST['number'];
if ($number1 > 0 && !($number1 < 0){
echo "greater than 0";
}
```

Still doesn't work...

echo gettype($number1)    returns: NULL

So i did the "print_r($_POST)"

and it returns:

```
Array
(
    [zombie] => -1
    [droid] => 0
    [alien] => 0
    [rpc] => 0
)
```

my form:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" value="0" name="zombie"> <br />
    <input type="number" class="form-control" value="0" name="droid"> <br />
    <input type="number" class="form-control" value="0" name="alien"> <br />
    <input type="number" class="form-control" value="0" name="rpc"> <br />
</form
```

Comment: first check your `$_POST['number']`  get values or not?

Comment: assign statically value to `$_POST['number']` its working and the problem behind post

Comment: you sure your form isn't failing you, the one you didn't post?

Comment: uhm when i test it with: echo gettype($number1)
the output is: NULL

Comment: post your full code and leave the guesswork out of things. Or, see the answer given below. I for one was never really good at doing guesswork, unless it was something I am used to knowing of an unknown.

Comment: @Epodax changed that.

Comment: All PHP developers need to know this: `echo "<pre>",print_r($_REQUEST),"</pre>";` - If it's an array, LOOK INSIDE IT! Don't just assume. :-)

Comment: Check my answer below, and check what is in this `$_POST['number']`

Comment: `$_POST['number']` there, you have NO input bearing the `number` name attribute which is why your code failed and have wasted everyone's time, including your own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable” and “Notice: Undefined index”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: why are you doing this Stealth editing????????? now I'm really out of this question.

Comment: i made a mistake there yes but still not working

Comment: waste of f'ing time.

Comment: I'm packing up guys...see ya later!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you just wrong posting your data? Check what is in `$_POST['number']`.

```
echo $_POST['number'];
```

You can always check your whole `$_POST` array, maybe you just made a mistake in your variable name? If you want to do it:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

There is no input in your code with `name="number"`
You need something like that:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" value="0" name="number"> <br />
```

Comment: why someone gives minus if answer shows better code?

Comment: Not the down voter but @marcus - Maybe because the code isn't actually better and a ternary operator isn't always the answer, the question is "How to check if value is greater than" not "How to check if value is set"

Comment: But there is still an question about what's in that `$_POST['number']`. I think you should focus on whole answer, not only at first line.

Comment: i did the print_r see above

Comment: You don't use answers to debug / request information from the asker, that's what ***comments*** are for.

Comment: @emielpopelier can you post what you got?

Comment: As you can see, there is no `'number'` in this array, please post us your `<form>`.

Comment: Do you get a badge for changing the most edits in a period of time?

Comment: @KarolGasienica *"please post us your <form>"* - I did that [*when?....*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262264/check-if-value-is-above-0-not-working#comment67784947_40262264) *lol!!* too funny. Not my downvote here btw.

Comment: @Kitson88 i bet there is no such thing, just trying to make a helpful answer. Let's focus on problem.

Comment: posted my form in my question above

Comment: If you want to use a `$_POST['number']` you need to make your input with
`name="number"`

Comment: yes i have that in my code but when i rewrote it here i made a mistake

Comment: Good :) We found a solution ;) If it helps, just accept my answer :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['button']))
{
$number = $_POST['zombie'];
    if($number > 0)
    {
        echo "number is greater";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "number is less";
    }
}

?>
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="number" class="form-control" value="0" name="zombie"> <br />
  <input type="number" class="form-control" value="0" name="droid"> <br />
  <input type="number" class="form-control" value="0" name="alien"> <br />
  <input type="number" class="form-control" value="0" name="rpc"> <br />
  <input type="submit" name="button" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Just need to add a button in the end of the form